# How can I update CefBrowser in WinForm with calls to API

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am having a tough time trying to get CefBrowser to send and update to an external API upon button click.

I am trying to POST and PUT form data (this is only PUT) collected and send it to an external URL, in this instance localhost so I can capture the receieved DTO and then do something with it before updating the page. IE `fieldOne` would update the the `<p id="heading"></p>` for arguement's sake.

I have tested through PostMan and the receiving API is working as intended, I set an alert in the Javascript to make sure that the JSON being sent matches that of the C# DTO, which it does.

In dev tools I receieve no error in the console nor nothing in the network tab.

The other posts I have seen are either old or I am finding them a bit confusing to follow.

Is what I am trying to achieve possible through just Javascript or do I need to utilise `browser.JavascriptMessageReceived += OnBrowserJavascriptMessageReceived;` & `browser.FrameLoadEnd += OnFrameLoadEnd;` and if so could I get some guidance on this please?

C# Browser class

```
public class Browser
{
    public ChromiumWebBrowser browser { get; set; }
    public ChromiumWebBrowser InitialiseBrowser()
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings()
        {
            CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
                         Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), @"CefSharp\Cache")
        };

        settings.RegisterScheme(new CefCustomScheme
        {
            SchemeName = "localfolder",
            SchemeHandlerFactory = new FolderSchemeHandlerFactory(
                rootFolder: @"WinFormWebUI\html",
                defaultPage: "index.html"
        )
        });

        Cef.Initialize(settings);
        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(@"localfolder://cefsharp");
        browser.JavascriptMessageReceived += OnBrowserJavascriptMessageReceived;
        browser.FrameLoadEnd += OnFrameLoadEnd;
        browser.LoadingStateChanged += BrowserLoadingStateChanged;
        // register JS and CSS using CDN for ease at the moment
        browser.BrowserSettings.FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
        browser.BrowserSettings.UniversalAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
        return browser;
    }

    private void BrowserLoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check to see if loading is complete - this event is called twice, one when loading starts
        // second time when it's finished
        // (rather than an iframe within the main frame).
        if (e.IsLoading) return;
        this.browser.ShowDevTools();
    }

    public void OnFrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Frame.IsMain)
        {
            //In the main frame we inject some javascript that's run on mouseUp
            //You can hook any javascript event you like.


            // do I just copy my script from the html into here rather than putting it in the html page?
        }
    }

    private void OnBrowserJavascriptMessageReceived(object sender, JavascriptMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // what would go in here?
    }
}
```

HTML and JS:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <p id="heading"></p>
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-8">
                        <form id="prototypeForm" class="form-group" onsubmit="formSubmit()">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="field1" name="field1" placeholder="Dummy text" />
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" id="field2" name="field2" placeholder="0" />
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="field3" name="field3" placeholder="Dummy text" />
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">My button </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<script>
    function formSubmit() {
            var formData = JSON.stringify($("#prototypeForm").serializeArray());
            alert(formData);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'PUT',
                url: 'https://localhost:5001/cef',
                data: formData,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            });
            return false;
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this your actual code structure? I don't know if it matters, but your script is outside your html element. Try moving it just before the end body tag.

Comment: Ooops. It should be just before </body>. You're right , doesn't change anything though, sadly.

Comment: also just for the heck of it - if you have dev console, can you tell if onsubmit is even firing? like a breakpoint in the function gets called? i'd be tempted to change the button type submit to input type submit if not in case it's some old compatibility thing

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I changed it just out of curiosity, they both work - the break point is hit, the alert which is in the function always displays with the form data in JSON format.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2775#issuecomment-498454221 in your case the http://cefsharp.github.io/api/88.2.x/html/P_CefSharp_JavascriptMessageReceivedEventArgs_Message.htm property will be a string if you pass in formData, just use a cast in c# and then you have the JSON, do whatever you like from there.

Comment: Oh brilliant, thank you, so is `CefSharp.PostMessage` instead of the entire AJAX function?

Comment: Oh, more like `function() formSubmit() { Cef.PostMessage(formData); }`